# Is there a way to export a Informatica maplet 'graphical' data to a simple csv/Excel file?

Tags: export, etl, informatica, system-analysis

The firm I work in has a lot of data sources entering the firm database using the Informatica ETL tool, stored in maplets and other data models (sorry If I'm not using the exact terminology).
The problem is that all the business logic is stored in the 'graphical interface' and nowhere else - Every time I want to see what field goes into the target field I have to trace the inputs through the maplet and that takes a very long time.

**The Question is:** Is there a tool that can takes all the relationships in the Informatica maplet and somehow export them to a excel table (so I can see it all without tracing)?  that way I could try to make proper documentation....

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can check infa repo metadata db for some info as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to export mappings or whole workflows to XML. Next, you can use this [tool](https://xmlanalyzer.maciejg.pl/) - it will create tables with source to target dependency for every mapping.

Keep in mind it will only map input to output, it won't extract the full logic and transformations done along the way - that would've been to complex for simple visualization.

Answer (score 0):

Informatica supports exporting mapping information to Excel - just search the documentation which  tells you how to do it.

However, for anything other than the simplest of mappings, what ends up in Excel is not that easy to understand. If your Informatica installation supports it, then using the lineage capabilities is a much better bet.